# Создать список объектов класса в php

Tags: php, списки

Есть класс:

```
class Alpha
{
    var $id;
    var $value;
}
```

Нужно создать список и добавить туда три объекта этого класса а потом циклом вывести поля. Помогите пожалуйста уже пробовал по разному.

```
class Arrays
{
    public function ArrayPlus()
    {
        $obj_1 = new Alpha();

        $obj_2 = new Alpha();

        list($obj_1, $obj_2) = $_list;

        echo $_list[1]->B;
    }
}
```

Comment: Напишите как пробовали, что не получается. А то вопрос выглядит так: "У меня есть задача, напишите мне код"

Comment: @Эдуард, добавил.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
class Arrays
{
    public function ArrayPlus()
    {
        $obj_1 = new Alpha();

        $obj_2 = new Alpha();

        $list = array();

        $list[] = $obj_1;

        $list[] = $obj_2;

        echo $list[0]->id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Alpha
{
    var $id;
    var $value;
    function __construct($_id, $_value) {
        $this->id = $_id;
        $this->value = $_value;
    }
}

class Beta
{     
    public function BetaFunction()
    {
         $object_1 = new Alpha(1, "qwe");
         $object_2 = new Alpha(2, "asd");

         $_1list = array($object_1, $object_2);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
        {
           echo $_1list[$i]->id;
           echo $_1list[$i]->value;
        }
    }
}
```